# phpMyAdmin and Java Connection

Tags: java, phpmyadmin

I am trying to connect my java program to a database that i have created using phpmyadmin using a university server. so the database is on the university server. how do i get the connection to the db from the java program? i have tried this code, but it gives me an error message?

```
import java.sql.Connection; 
import java.sql.DriverManager; 
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Connector {
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;

    Connector()
    {
    try{

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("https://NAMEHIDDEN.soi.city.ac.uk:5454/~kdhy546","root","");

                    stmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from staff where username=? and password=?");
                    }

    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

I am not too sure even, whether this is the correct url to the database? how do i determine the exact link to the database in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 3):

phpMyAdmin in not a DBMS, it's an UI. If it's a MySQL database, you must use the [MySQL JDBC](http://dev.mysql.com/usingmysql/java/)

Comment: I edited my answer by adding the link to the official MySQL documentation

Comment: i have used the mysql jdbc. it worked when i had a localhost link. now i uploaded the database onto the server, so i just got to change the location of the database in the connection class, but i am just not too sure, what link to put in there? cos normally, when u want to access the db on the server, you need to type in usernames, passwords, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I have never used phpMyAdmin, but according to [this](http://teamtutorials.com/web-development-tutorials/create-mysql-databse-with-cpanel-and-phpmyadmin#.T1YZnvEgc4Q) tutorial you should get the connection string if you navigate to the MySQL Account Maintenance Section.

Another thing I am noticing is that you are missing your password in your connection, so without a password your application will not be able to connect.

Lastly, whenever you post a question on SO regarding some code which yields an error, please make sure you include the error, it helps us help you :).

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code.
This is the java part:

```java
    import java.net.*;

    public class mc
     {
     public static void main(String args[])
   {
    try
      {
     String username="ankur",password="ankur",fname="Shubhendu",ip="12345",lname="Goswami";
     String up= "username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&fname=" + fname + "&lname=" + lname + "&ip="+ ip;
     URL url=new URL("http://127.0.0.1:80/alias1/index.php?"+up);
     URLConnection urlc=url.openConnection();
     urlc.connect();
     BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlc.getInputStream()));
     String str;
     while((str=br.readLine())!=null)
       {
         System.out.print(str);
       }

     br.close();        
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
   }
```

PHP part: Anything you will echo from PHP will be stored in String `str` in Java code:

```php
         <?php

          mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die("unable to connect to server");
          mysql_select_db("db_name") or die("Unable to connect to database");

          $username=$_GET['username'];
          $password=md5($_GET['password']);
          $fname=$_GET['fname'];
          $lname=$_GET['lname'];
          $ip=$_GET['ip'];
          if(isset($username) && isset($password) && isset($fname) && isset($lname) && isset($ip))
           {
        $query="INSERT INTO tablename values('$username','$password','$fname','$lname','$ip')";
        $fire=mysql_query($query);
        }   
           ?>
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL to the database you created with phpMyAdmin is wrong.  It should look something similar to:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//myhost:1521/orc
```

I recommend you to have a web search for some good Java tutorials on this subject. :)

Comment: yeh i just found out it shouldbe jdbc:mysql:URL but then, i dont know how to get the direct URL for my database. how do i get that for a database?

Comment: I think you put a forward slash, then whatever the name you gave it when it was created... i.e. jdbc:mysql:127.0.0.1:3359/pitabase You will need to ensure proper permissions for your user to access the database remotely also!

Comment: shouldn't matter provided you can resolve the name and that you have proper permissions on the server to access the database remotely.

Comment: hmm it doesnt work for some reason. need to try and error i guess.

Comment: Most times i've had trouble with this, its due to permissions for the user on the database or access to the server remotely OR firewall problems!  You can always look into reverse tunnelling into the database through ssh and point your code to your local forwarded port.  Checkout "ssh -L" command... :)

Comment: my error message says must specify port after':' in connection string. any idea what it means?

Comment: sure, the mysql server runs on a specific port which remote clients can connect to, this is usually 3306 (but can change).  You need to find out what port your server is running on and if you can connect to it remotely on this port. Above, my exemplar URL is trying to connect on port 1521, yours is likely to be 3306.

Comment: hmm i tried putting the port number there as well, no luck! weird!

Comment: I have `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/db_structure.php?db=vidya&token=fbac38e581c23c100ad616e8357ded6a` how can I find the URL for JDBC?